# Would I be able to move my Linux OS from a USB stick to my computer's hard drive?

Tags: usb-drive, migration

The point is, I want to gradually migrate my data and workflows to Linux without compromising the hard drive's space. I thought I could install Linux to a thumb drive, install apps and whatnot, and, when I'm ready, move the OS to the computer.

Comment: it is possible, but it is unknown if you would be able to do it ... sounds like a hard way to do it

Comment: Welcome to unix.stackexchange.com, m_ocean.  Can you explain how you plan on doing what you propose ? Right now, I'm afraid the picture is a little too fuzzy for you to get any serious attention.

Comment: A thumb drive is a disk, just like the hard drive in your computer. If you understand how partitions work, you can create new ones in the hard drive (maybe resizing the old ones, **DO** make a backup) and then move the system. It's a bit more involved than that, but that should broadly answer the question. For more precise answers you will probably have to write a more detailed question.

Comment: Think about your data - it is more important than the OS. Take backups of the thumbdrive as their long term reliability is poor.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be possible: https://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing-components/storage/how-to-move-your-operating-system-to-another-hard-drive-1296831